# Set a page as the default page in Plesk

Tags: plesk

How can I set a page as a default page in Plesk. for example, when somebody requests www.mysite.com, it will automatically open www.mysite.com/Index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it, you need first to go to your Home Page in Plesk Panael, choose virtual directories, then choose your domain, then choose Directory Propertories

Answer (score 1):

Or to use Web.Config but the recommended way is to use from virtual directories

```
    <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
          <defaultDocument enabled="true">
             <files>
                <add value="home.html" />
             </files>
          </defaultDocument>
       </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Apache is usually set to index.php or index.html

You may use .htaccess on linux servers and set the default page in Plesk website

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html site-down.php
```

Answer (score 0):

this kind of done via .htaccess in Linux file of made URL rewrite changes in IIS for windows.

Like

```
.htaccess 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the website is opening index.html (displays default page provided by the web hosting company), and you want the default page to be controlled by index.php, delete (or rename index.html) and it will automatically pickup index.php as the startup file. At least that is how it works with Peer 1.